# Value from default field initialization is not being assigned

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, initialization

I'm currently working on a lab for my operating systems class and I'm having trouble understanding why the value I specify in a class' default field initialization is not being assigned. I have the following scheduler class:

```
class LOOK : SSTF {
public:
    io_req* pop() override;
};
```

That inherits from this scheduler:

```
class SSTF : protected IOSched {
public:
    virtual io_req* pop() override;
    virtual void push(io_req* new_req) override;
protected:
    io_req* left_pop();
    io_req* right_pop();
    int dir;
    LinkedList left;
    LinkedList right;   
};
```

Where IOSched is a pure virtual class with the pop() and push() methods and a curr_req field, and this is the LinkedList class:

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    io_req* pop();
    void push(io_req* new_req);
    void push_in_order(io_req* new_req);
    io_req* top() const;
    void reset_dist(io_req* new_curr);
private:
    void insert_between(io_req_node* new_prev, io_req_node* new_next, io_req_node* new_node);
    io_req_node* head = nullptr;
    io_req_node* tail = nullptr;
};
```

From my understanding of C++, when I allocate a new LOOK object as such:

`sched = (IOSched*)(new LOOK());`

I will get a pointer to a heap-allocated `LOOK` object which will contain an `SSTF` object, which will contain two `LinkedList` objects, `left` and `right`, which will be initialized with `head` and `tail` as `nullptr`.

However, for some reason I am getting a value of `0x203d1` for `left.head` while `0x0` for the rest. This only happens when `sched` is initialized as a `LOOK` object and not when it `SSTF` (for the lab I have to implement a few different algorithms).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide us with enough code that we could run it and test it ourselves? I've attempted to reproduce the issue, but I'm unable to do so.

Comment: Here's the code I used to try and reproduce it https://godbolt.org/z/A9a3hu

Comment: Here's one that actually compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/wXt_9m

Comment: You're going to need to post an [mcve] . You're obviously doing something wrong, but it doesn't appear to be in the code that you've selected to share with us.

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez https://godbolt.org/z/zcDjtw here is code that would get to the same point in the program, however for some reason I can't get it to reproduce the same issue...

Comment: Also, in C++ you don't do this: `sched = (IOSched*)(new LOOK());` . Just `sched = new LOOK();` is correct.

Comment: Anyhow, you're probably clobbering your memory somewhere.   Build it with -fsanitize=address and run it again.   You'll probably get some interesting output.

Comment: @xaxxon when I run it with that flag I don't get this issue. Any idea why?

Comment: try with `-fsanitize=undefined` then :)    You've got some weirdness going on.  Seriously, post an [mcve] and we can actually help you.

Comment: @xaxxon also, the reason I do `sched = (IOSched*)(new LOOK());` is because I initialize it as different schedulers at runtime depending on an argument to the program

Comment: That cast does nothing.  Pointers are implicitly convertible to pointers to a base type.  It's a waste of typing when you're doing it right, and it can hide errors if you do it wrong (the pointer type ISN'T compatible).  In general you don't want to use c-style casts, anyhow - they offer no type safety.

Comment: Wait.  Are you doing that because it's complaining that you're not allowed to assign that because you're doing protected inheritance?

Comment: @xaxxon https://send.firefox.com/download/532a39d724858cce/#KScTFfknLrqVr84rCq1FiQ here is a .tar of the code. To reproduce run `make` and then `./iosched -ss ./input1`. The `-ss` flag selects the LOOK algorithm to run. You can also run it with `-si` or `-sj` to see behavior when using other schedule algos.

Comment: @xaxxon yea, it's telling me IOSched is an inaccessible base. Is there a better way to solve that? thanks so much for the input!

Comment: The deepest part of hell is reserved for people who make tar files that explode into the current directory!  -- yeah, do public inheritance not protected.  And then don't try to override the compiler when it tells you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @xaxxon apologies, kind of new to using tar! how do I avoid it from exploding?

Comment: tar cvf some_dir.tar some_dir/    also, it seems to be working fine for me.   https://gist.github.com/xaxxon/f1aef5e948cfbe2e117754711994a726

Comment: @xaxxon after I used public inheritence it started working for me as well... idk man... thanks for the help and the tips on tar and inheritance tho!

Answer (score 1):

```
sched = (IOSched*)(new LOOK());
```

You cannot cast a pointer to a protected base class outside of the class:

```
class A{};

class B : protected A {
    void foo(){
        B b;
        A * a = &b; // this is ok
    }
};

int main() {
    A * a = new B; // this is not
}
```

Use public inheritance instead - that's almost always what you want in a traditional object-oriented situation.

Also, don't use c-style casts in c++.   If you used static_cast, it would have continued to yell at you as you deserved to be yelled at :)

Answer (score -3):

Non-static member initialisation is an extension of C++11 (see [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language-classes#member-init)).

Since your members are not static, you have to initialize them in the constructor initialisation list:

```
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    io_req* pop();
    void push(io_req* new_req);
    void push_in_order(io_req* new_req);
    io_req* top() const;
    void reset_dist(io_req* new_curr);
private:
    void insert_between(io_req_node* new_prev, io_req_node* new_next, io_req_node* new_node);
    io_req_node* head ; // useless = nullptr;
    io_req_node* tail , // useless = nullptr;
};
```

Or switch to C++11 or higher.

Comment: That's a compiler error if he's not using at least c++11. https://godbolt.org/z/0L38Fj . He wouldn't be getting ANY values (right or wrong) if he had a compiler error.   We can safely say this is not the answer.

Comment: yeah, using c++11 for this.